# log recursion from jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I'm trying to calculate a series with a recursive function and jQuery but I don't know how to log each recursion that the function is making so I could get the series members.

the code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var n = $("#number").val();
        function series(n) {
            if (n == 1) {
                return 6;
            } else {
                return 0.5 * series(n - 1) + 4;
            }
        }
        console.log(series(n));
    });
});
```

The problem is that the function only logs the last series member. For example if `n = 4` the series should be 6, 7, 7.5, 7.75.

The function only returns 7.75.

This is the series formula: `series(n) = 0.5 * series(n - 1) + 4`, if `n = 1` then `series(n) = 6`;
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most beautiful looking example, but if you take your code and then wrap it in another function with a results array. Then call your inner recursive function and store them to that array it can return the results as an array. You can then use a join to make it into a string to display using jQuery or console log it.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/hPWuW/

```
function getSeriesArray(n) {
    var results = [];
    function series(n) {
        if (n === 1) {
            results.push(6);
            return 6;
        } else {
            var result = 0.5 * series(n - 1) + 4;
            results.push(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
    series(n);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it gets the job done! But it's so complicated. In Visual Basic or C++ it's easier. No arrays involved, just puere recursion and iteration print. I'll keep investigating, there has to be a simpler way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `console.log()` is only accepting the output of the outermost series call. If you want to log every iteration you either need to log inside your series method or keep track of every result during the iterations in the series method and then log whatever you used to keep track.

This seems like homework so I wont give too much away, but it might help is used the inspector in browser to walked the execution and get a feel for how the code is flowing.

Comment: :) it's not homework. I'm trying to learn about recursive functions. I've tried putting the `console.log(series(n))` inside the function but it returns a "maximum call stack size exceded". How can I keep track of every iteration? I've tried with a "counter" variable but didn't work.

Comment: How about storing them in an array?

Comment: The "maximum call stack size exceeded" is a fundamental issue with the way you've created your recursive function. Quick question: what happens if `n` is never 1?

Comment: n must be 1 every time, because the series must return every value of n up until it reaches the value given to series(n). For example if I want series(7) the function has to return: series(7), series(6), series(5), series(4), series(3), series(2), series(1).

Comment: and, Josh, I don't realy care storing the values in an array, I just can't figure out how to print the freakin' values of every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var n = $("#number").val();
        function series(n) {
            var val=6;
            if (n != 1) {
               val= 0.5 * series(n - 1) + 4;
            }
            console.log(val);
            return val;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything :(

Comment: It returns the val at the end after printing the output in the console